# Regex optional substring in the pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string as `Failed to acquire capacity on the hall`
And sometimes I might also get `Failed to acquire new capacity on the hall`.
So to cover both the cases I want to make `new` as optional.

So I grouped new with `?` as `(new)?` in the pattern as below

pattern : `failed to acquire (new)? capacity`.

But its not working as expected, i.e matching `Failed to acquire capacity on the hall` even though `new` is there or not. Ref: https://regex101.com/r/2YhjKc/1

What is the mistake I am doing here ?

Thank you.

Comment: you have an extra space after `new`. Include the space or remove it: `failed to acquire (new )? capacity`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word `new` is also surrounded with whitespace, which you should also take into account, e.g.

```
failed to acquire\s+(new\s+)?capacity
```

### Demo